# How to get Text in GridView when selected?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps, programmatically-created

I'm working on a project in which I'm setting content using JSON Binding in Grid view but now I want to get Text of item when it is selected. XAML CODE:

```
 <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" x:Name="dataList" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionMode="None" SelectionChanged="dataList_Selection">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Width="450" Height="300">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Top}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="None" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="title" Text="{Binding Title}"   Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Assets/Font/MixBrush.ttf#MixBrush"  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="50" Margin="0,10,0,0"  />
                <Image Source="{Binding Bottom}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="None" />
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding first}"   Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontFamily="Assets/Font/Comfortaa_Regular.ttf#Comfortaa"   FontSize="20" Margin="0,50,0,0"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding second}"   Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontFamily="Assets/Font/Comfortaa_Regular.ttf#Comfortaa"   FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,0,0"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding third}"   Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontFamily="Assets/Font/Comfortaa_Regular.ttf#Comfortaa"   FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,0,0"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Here I want to get Text of "title" programmatically. Please share your knowledge with me. :-) 


********************** Thank You ************************

Answer (score 0):

On your back code use:

```
title.Text;
```

Comment: For your very kind information I'm using "title" inside data template and it is not reachable programmatically..!! :)

Comment: "For your very kind information" :D :D :D sorry, I didn't notice that :)

Comment: No problem bro .. :)

Answer (score 0):

After long hard struggle I found my answer.

```
var selection = (myClass) dataList.SelectedItem;
await new MessageDialog(selection.Title).ShowAsync();
```

And I got perfect result.

**Thank You.**